# Fire event after two keypress

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm just wondering if there is a way to fire an event after two keypress for example, after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice. I tried by keeping track of the first event in a variable, is there a better way?

Comment: "I tried by keeping track of the first event in a variable" -> Did it work? Is the question only about the better way or about "if there is a way"?

Comment: It worked. I'm looking for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution

**code:**

```
var ct=[];
$('#txtSearch').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if((e.which || e.keyCode) === 13){
        ct[ct.length]=1;
        var count=ct.length;
        if(count%2==0){
        alert("Enter pressed twice");
        // Remove the alert and place your code here
        }
    }
});
```

This will display an alert every time the 'Enter' key is pressed twice.

Here is a working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gx4oke94/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
$('selector').on('twoenter', fn); var counter = 0; // bind here
$('input').keypress(function(e){
   if((e.which || e.keyCode) === 13) counter++
   if(counter === 2) $('selector').trigger("twoenter"); // trigger here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count keypress Enter
for example:

```
var count = 0;
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
if(e.key == 'Enter')
count += 1;
if(count > 1) {
//your code must be there that you want to run after twice press enter
console.log('Twice Enter');
}
setTimeout(function() { count = 0;}, 500);
});
```